# Botframework with Reactjs is not working on IE11

Tags: reactjs, botframework, chatbot, web-chat

botframework with react is not working in IE,

I'm using my index html file similar to
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/03.a.host-with-react, its working in chrome but not in IE, i tried using webchat-es5.js also.

I'm using token given by bot team.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Integrate with React</title>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.5.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.5.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@5.0.7/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }
      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>

   <script type="text/babel">
      function start() {
            const { createStore, ReactWebChat } = window.WebChat;
            const { Provider } = window.ReactRedux;
            const store = createStore();

            window.ReactDOM.render(
             <Provider store={ store }>
               <ReactWebChat
                  directLine={ window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token:'mytoken' }) }
                 storeKey="webchat"
               />
             </Provider>,
             document.getElementById('webchat')
           );

            document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      }
      start();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

working in Chrome but not in IE, somebody help me on this please.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatley, the "webchat-es5.js" package was designed for instantiating web chat via the `window.WebChat.renderWebChat` method. While the "webchat.js" package does allow for using `window.ReactDOM.render`, it is **not** designed for older browsers, such as IE.

I played with this a bunch and was simply unable to render web chat using `window.ReactDOM.render` while also in IE, despite utilizing any number of polyfills. That being said, I *was* able to get the [hosted React web chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/03.a.host-with-react/index.html) sample to work in a proper React project with a few of modifications. Please note, this also makes use of webpack.

Hope of help!

**index.js:** Nothing special or unexpected here.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import './css/index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**app.js:** Just some necessary routing.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import WebChatView from './webChatView';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" exact component={WebChatView} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**webChatView.js:** Renders the web chat page (with some necessary styling)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WebChatView from './webchatView';

const FragmentStyling = {
  'container': {
    'display': 'flex',
    'justifyContent': 'center'
  },
  'div': {
    'height': '40rem',
    'minHeight': '20rem',
    'width': '1200px',
    'display': 'flex',
    'justifyContent': 'space-around',
    'marginTop': '2rem'
  }
}

class WebChatView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={FragmentStyling.container}>
        <div style={FragmentStyling.div}>
          <WebChatView id="webchat" role="main" />
        </div >
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default WebChatView;
```

**webchat.js:** Several things to note:

1. Either `import '@babel/polyfill'` needs to be included or all the 'core-js' imports listed below. Babel recommends importing only the required polyfills (to keep package size down). Those shown below are what is needed. However, using the '@babel' option works, as well.
2. Simply using `fetch` as-is breaks due to compatibility issues. There may be other options, but the below 'whatwg-fetch' option works in both IE and Chrome. Others I tested did not.
3. 'fetching' the token needs to be promise-based. Using async/await breaks React web chat in IE.

```js
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/promise'
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/fn/array/find-index';
import 'core-js/fn/array/includes';
import 'core-js/fn/math/sign';
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import 'core-js/fn/string/starts-with';

import { fetch as fetchPolyfill } from 'whatwg-fetch';

import React from 'react';
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';

export default class WebChat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      directLine: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchToken();
  }

  fetchToken(token) {
    fetchPolyfill('http://localhost:3500/directline/token', { method: 'POST' })
      .then(res => res.json()) // expecting a json response
      .then(json =>
        this.setState(() => ({
          directLine: createDirectLine(
            {
              token: json.token
            }
          )
        }))
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.directLine ?
        <ReactWebChat
          directLine={this.state.directLine}
        />
        :
        <div>Connecting to bot&hellip;</div>
    )
  }
}
```

**index.html:** The 'react-polyfill.min.js' package needs to be included and should precede any other scripts that might live here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//pitzcarraldo.github.io/react-polyfill/react-polyfill.min.js" charSet="UTF-8"></script>
    <title>React Web App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js:** The `import 'script!react-polyfill'` needs to be included at the top of this file.

```js
import 'script!react-polyfill';

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  mode: 'development'
};
```